# How to define a Ruby method that either takes an Array or a String?

Tags: arrays, ruby, string

I defined a method that takes an Array (of Strings), like

```
def list(projects)
  puts projects.join(', ')
end

list(['a', 'b'])
```

However, as a short-hand for calling it with an Array that only consists of a single String element, I'd like the same function to also accept a single plain String like

```
  list('a')
```

What would be the Ruby way to handle this inside the method?

Comment: `Array(projects).join(', ')`

Comment: Make that comment into an answer, it's the right way.

Comment: Seriously, @LeeJarvis, post that as an answer so we can upvote it.

Comment: @DavidMoles: 18 months later, I think it's safe to say Lee won't mind if someone else takes his comment and posts it as an answer. Frankly, it's not against community standards to use someone else's comment as the basis for an answer, even if the comment is only minutes old. A decent answer takes more effort to write up than an off-hand comment, and often the commenter has no intention of investing that effort. More power to the person who runs with the idea and provides something useful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why not something like this:

```
def list(*projects)
  projects.join(', ')
end
```

Then you can call it with as many arguments as you please

```
list('a')
#=> "a"
list('a','b')
#=> "a, b"
arr = %w(a b c d e f g)
list(*arr)
#=> "a, b, c, d, e, f, g"
list(arr,'h','i')
#=> "a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i"
```

The splat (*) will automatically convert all arguments into an Array,  this will allow you to pass an Array and/or a String without issue. It will work fine with other objects too

```
list(1,2,'three',arr,{"test" => "hash"}) 
#=> "1, 2, three, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, {\"test\"=>\"hash\"}"
```

<sup><sub>Thank you @Stefan and @WandMaker for pointing out `Array#join` can handle nested Arrays</sub></sup>

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I know i just wanted to show all the ways it can be used without any concern for errors. Plus originally I didn't have the flatten in there and then I figured since the OP asked to pass a true array this would be the easiest way to handle this.

Comment: Why is `flatten` needed? When I tried `projects.join(', ')` it seems to give desired result

Comment: @WandMaker without `flatten`, `list(['a', 'b'])` would result in a nested array. Removing `flatten` works in this case because `join` can handle nested arrays.

Comment: @stefan and @wandmaker thank you I didn't even try just using `#join`.  Answer updated.

Comment: _this will allow you to pass an Array and/or a String without issue_—I don't think this is strictly true. It works because `join` handles nested arrays, but consider something like `def count_args(*p); p.size; end`—`count_args(*arr)` will return 7, but `count_args(arr)` will return 1. The caller still needs to know to splat the array.

Comment: @DavidMoles yes for your case but not the presented case as you pointed out `Array#join` handles nested Arrays so my statement is true

Comment: @engineersmnky I'm sorry you're taking it personally. If you run across one of my answers while searching for information and find it steers you in the wrong direction, by all means comment and downvote.

Answer (score 4):

You can check the type of the input, for example:

```
>> a = ['foo', 'bar']
=> ['foo', 'bar']
>> a.is_a? Array
=> true
```

you can also check string with `is_a?`

You would end up with something link:

```
def list(projects)
    if projects.is_a? Array
        puts projects.join(', ')
    else
        puts projects
    end
end

list('a') # a
list(['a', 'b']) # a, b
```

You have many ways of doing this in Ruby, `respond_to?` and `kind_of?` also work

Answer (score 3):

One way would be you could type-check the input:

```
def list(projects)
  if projects.is_a?(String)
    projects = [projects]
  end
  puts projects.join(', ')
end
```

Or you could use `Array()` to auto-convert a string into an array, or leave an existing array alone:

```
def list(projects)
  Array(projects).join(', ')
end
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def list(projects)
  puts Array(projects).join(', ')
end

list ['a', 'b']
a, b
list 'a'
a
```

One could alternatively write

```
puts [*projects].join(', ')
```

A caveat: don't use this.

I posted this solution only to show two ways it could be done. @sawa, in his now-deleted answer, is right: users of the method should not be permitted to pass an array as an argument. Instead, they should be restricted to passing individual elements. If:

```
arr = [1,2,3]
```

the method would be called by one of the following:

```
list 1
list 1,2
list 1,2,3
list *arr
```

but not:

```
list arr
```

This simplifies the method and makes its application more consistent. Ask yourself this: why permit `arr` in lieu of `*arr`? To save one character?

The method that does this is @engineersmnky's answer with `.flatten` removed.

Comment: I've voted to undelete [sawa's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31704638/477037), accepting *either* an array *or* a list of objects is the way to go. Trying to handle both is cumbersome.

Comment: @Stefan, I didn't know one can vote to undelete an answer. That's weird, but there are now two votes. Perhaps sawa will yield to our wishes and voluntarily undelete it.

Comment: For the record, I didn't suggest removing `flatten` :)

Comment: @Sergio, I don't know how I totally misread your comment, but since a string doesn't respond to `flatten`, I don't understand what your meant.

Comment: BTW, `[*obj]` can have unexpected results if `obj` responds to `to_a`. Try `list(Time.now)`

Comment: `[*projects]` is equivalent to `Array(projects)` isn't it?

Comment: @CarySwoveland: I meant that he didn't _need_ to do splatting: `list(*ary)`. Could have just done `list(ary)`, because of the `flatten` there.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev `ary` could be a string, you can't `flatten` a string

Comment: @Stefan: I think Cary and I, we're talking about engineersmnky's answer. String doesn't have a chance to be flattened there.

Comment: @Stefan, with regard to your last comment, I think so. I noticed Lee Jarvis mentioned that in a comment on the question.  Your penultimate comment is interesting. Readers:  `[*Time.now][5] #=> 2015`.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev of course. The splat is needed to convert `ary` to an array. Otherwise `list('a')` would result in `'a'.flatten`

Comment: @Stefan: read the answer. And I was talking about splatting in the method *call*, not method definition.

Comment: @Stefan: maybe it's called differently. I call both usages "splatting" :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev sorry, I was talking about the splat in `def list(*projects)` and could not understand your point :-)

Comment: @Stefan: yeah, I figured :)

Comment: This is the longest conversation about any one of my answers and it's not even on my answer. :)

Comment: @sawa, care to undelete your answer?

Answer (score 1):

I would ask the provided value if it responds to `join`:

```
def list(projects)
  projects.respond_to?(:join) ? projects.join(', ') : projects 
end
```